# Unable to view ganglia web in browser

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, nagios, ganglia

I can run gmond, gmetad and httpd without errors. When I run gstat -an I get

```
CLUSTER INFORMATION
       Name: cluster
       Hosts: 1 
       Gexec Hosts: 0  
       Dead Hosts: 0   
       Localtime: Fri Sep 18 12:18:06 2015

CLUSTER HOSTS Hostname                     LOAD                       CPU              Gexec  
CPUs (Procs/Total) [     1,     5, 15min] [  User,  Nice, System, Idle, Wio]

    192.168.1.63
        4 (    0/  104) [  0.00,  0.01,  0.04] [   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,  99.9,   0.1] OFF
```

but when I try to access gweb from a bowser on 192.168.1.63/ganglia I get nothing, a blank page.

In httpd.conf I declared `ServerName 192.168.1.63:80`

In gmond.conf in udp_send_channel: `host: 192.168.1.63`

In gmetad.conf `data_source "cluster" 10 192.168.1.63:8649`

I'm not familiar with ganglia so don't have any idea what's going wrong. Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you user5359534 but my fault was that I hadn't enabled x11 forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

The output of `gstat` shows that the `udp_send_channel`, `udp_recv_channel` and `tcp_accept_channel` of your `gmond` are configured properly.

The configured `data_source` of your gmetad should be okay as well. To proof this suggestion you can check the `rrd_rootdir` for content.

The problem could be either `gweb` or `apache`. If you install `gweb` from your vendors repository the `conf_default.php` should already point to the correct directoies by default.

```
$conf['gmetad_root'] = "/var/lib/ganglia";
$conf['rrds'] = "${conf['gmetad_root']}/rrds";
```

If these paths are correct chances are high that your `apache` has been missconfigured.

Is it possible to post the relevant part of your `apache` configuration? What Linux Distribution are you using? Did you installed Ganglia from a repository?